# pyinstaller compatibility issue?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I use Ubuntu 22.04, pyinstaller 5.0.1, python 3.10.4 and wxPython 4.1.2a1.

My software runs well.

But I can't build the distribution package, even if I use "hidden-import". I don't have any building error, but the various libraries are not generated at all, and my software can't run.

I think it is related to the fact I can't run "--windowed" option, because of error message :

```
redge@redge-VirtualBox:~/Developpement/GestConsoPhoenix4.1.x--1.3.9$ source env4.1.x-py310/bin/activate
(env4.1.x-py310) redge@redge-VirtualBox:~/Developpement/GestConsoPhoenix4.1.x--1.3.9$ pyinstaller -w --distpath ./Dist myprogram.spec
686 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.0.1
686 INFO: Python: 3.10.4
687 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.15.0-27-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
  option(s) not allowed:
  --console/--nowindowed/--windowed/--noconsole
makespec options not valid when a .spec file is given
(env4.1.x-py310) redge@redge-VirtualBox:~/Developpement/GestConsoPhoenix4.1.x--1.3.9$
```

But without the windowed option, pyinstaller does not generate correctly : no librarie is generated (neither wxPython, nor matplotlib, and others like reportlab/openpyxl/xlsxwriter).

Is there some kind of incompatibility with the various programs I use, or another reason ?

Thanks for reading and any help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem solved with the new pyinstaller 5.1 version :)